# ¿Como agregar un listener a la cabecera de un navigation Drawer?

Tags: android, android-studio

Me gustaría poder **seleccionar** la foto del nav header main para que devuelva una **acción**. Es posible lograrlo por medio de **código** como por ejemplo con un click listener? En dicho caso, que **clase java** se vincularía con esta actividad como para poder relacionar los elementos y poder empezar a codear? **Agradecería** que lo compartan.

**Adjunto una foto para que comprendan a que me refiero.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**ACLARACION:** La imágen que muestro no es de mi actividad, sino de un video en youtube. Yo solo tengo una aplicación vacía a excepción del navigation Drawer que crea Android Studio por defecto.

Comment: Por favor lee [ask], considera editar y mostrar lo que llevas, ya que del modo actual es amplia y basada en opiniones y pudiera terminar cerrada

Comment: Ya llevo un tiempo en el sitio y se preguntar. La respuesta no puede ser a, b, c, d o hasta la z. La respuesta es solo una. Si sabes de programación en Android Studio entonces sabrás que el nav drawer lo crea automáticamente android studio por lo que mostrar ese mismo código no aportaría nada a la pregunta.

Comment: no has intentado agregar el listener al header del navigation view??

Comment: Eso es justamente lo que estoy prreguntando :(. Si sabes como hacerlo, por favor responde y te puntúo.

Comment: @TomasM de preferencia si investigaste algo y lo trataste puedes agregarlo a tu pregunta, eso ayuda a que otros respondan de una mejor manera tus preguntas, saludos! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para realizar esto debes encontrar la vista del Header:

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
View headerview = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
```

y buscar en esta el "header" para asignarle el listener :

```
LinearLayout header = (LinearLayout) headerview.findViewById(R.id.header);
//Asigna listener.
header.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

             //Realiza acción.            

        }
    });
```

Comment: Elena, no lo puedo creer!!! Solucionaste mi problema. Muchisimas gracias!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Un placer ayudarte amigo, saludos!